# paramiko SSHClient connect stuck

Tags: python, import, connect, paramiko

i have 3 source code(main and imported from it).

### test.py - just import file

```
import test_child
```

### test_child.py - call function defined in imported file

```
import test_grandchild

test_grandchild.check_sshd()
```

### test_grandchild.py - define function

```
import paramiko

def check_sshd():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print('checking ssh connection to local host')
    client.connect('127.0.0.1')
    client.close()
    print('finished')
```

check_ssd() is a fucntion just for checking sshd is running on localhost, So it is my expecting that Authentication execption occur when sshd is not running, otherwise socket error.
When i run test_child.py, result is in my expecting. but paramiko client get stucked on connect() and I have to terminate the process.

```
$ python test.py                                                                        
checking ssh connection to local host
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import test_child
  File "/root/tests/test_child.py", line 6, in <module>
    test_grandchild.check_sshd()
  File "/root/tests/test_grandchild.py", line 10, in check_sshd
    client.connect('127.0.0.1')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 242, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 342, in start_client
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 621, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout, balancing)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 361, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

how can i solve this problem?

Paramiko 1.12.4 on CentOS 7

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Paramiko** uses **Threading** library to distribute tasks to different threads, and event is set then they communicate with each other and return output. The problem here is in **test.py** you are just importing the test_child not calling any of its function specifically.

So the execution point to call **check_sshd()** is **test_child.py** not **test.py**. Hence threading event is not set. So for this either you call function from same file or you need to specifically call function from test.py rather than just importing file.

**test.py**

```
import test_child

test_child.check_ssh_connection()
```

**test_child.py**

```
import test_grandchild
def check_ssh_connection():
    test_grandchild.check_sshd()
```

**test_grandchild.py**

```
import paramiko

def check_sshd():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print('checking ssh connection to local host')
    client.connect('127.0.0.1')
    client.close()
    print('finished')
```

Hopefully this would solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for answering. I could understand what is wrong on my code.

In my case, i realized this problem while coding unittest.
`  test suites code for running all test suites
                  |
  test suites code for running test one module
                  |
  modules for application`
I don't like the case that top level test suites code must know what is in the lower code, so I'm gonna change code for checking sshd running as one testcase code with unittest.skip decorator.

But i could not do well because of another problem. I will post it as another topic.